# How to show age_range from Facebook Graph API PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to build a Login system with Facebook. And I want to get age_range from it.

Code is successfully to show id, username, etc. But not show age_range.
How to show age_range?

Here is my code

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,locale,picture,age_range');
$user = new Users();
$user_data = $user->checkUser('facebook',$user_profile['id'],$user_profile['first_name'],$user_profile['last_name'],$user_profile['email'],$user_profile['gender'],$user_profile['locale'],$user_profile['picture']['data']['url'],$user_profile['age_range']);
if(!empty($user_data)){
    $output = '<h1>Facebook Profile Details </h1>';
    $output .= '<img src="'.$user_data['picture'].'">';
    $output .= '<br/>Facebook ID : ' . $user_data['oauth_uid'];
    $output .= '<br/>Name : ' . $user_data['fname'].' '.$user_data['lname'];
    $output .= '<br/>Email : ' . $user_data['email'];
    $output .= '<br/>Usia : ' . $user_data['age_range'];
    $output .= '<br/>Gender : ' . $user_data['gender'];
    $output .= '<br/>Locale : ' . $user_data['locale'];
    $output .= '<br/>You are login with : Facebook';
    $output .= '<br/>Logout from <a href="logout.php?logout">Facebook</a>';
```

Sorry, this is function of checkUser:

```
function checkUser($oauth_provider,$oauth_uid,$fname,$lname,$email,$gender,$locale,$picture){

    $prev_query = mysqli_query($this->connect,"SELECT * FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE oauth_provider = '".$oauth_provider."' AND oauth_uid = '".$oauth_uid."'") or die(mysql_error($this->connect));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($prev_query)>0){
        $update = mysqli_query($this->connect,"UPDATE $this->table_name SET oauth_provider = '".$oauth_provider."', oauth_uid = '".$oauth_uid."', fname = '".$fname."', lname = '".$lname."', email = '".$email."', gender = '".$gender."', locale = '".$locale."', picture = '".$picture."', modified = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' WHERE oauth_provider = '".$oauth_provider."' AND oauth_uid = '".$oauth_uid."'");
    }else{
        $insert = mysqli_query($this->connect,"INSERT INTO $this->table_name SET oauth_provider = '".$oauth_provider."', oauth_uid = '".$oauth_uid."', fname = '".$fname."', lname = '".$lname."', email = '".$email."', gender = '".$gender."', locale = '".$locale."', picture = '".$picture."', created = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."', modified = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."'");
    }

    $query = mysqli_query($this->connect,"SELECT * FROM $this->table_name WHERE oauth_provider = '".$oauth_provider."' AND oauth_uid = '".$oauth_uid."'");
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: What does checkUser do?

Comment: I don't know too. I just download code from http://demos.codexworld.com/login-with-facebook-using-php/index.php

Comment: I have browse all file and i did'nt found checkUser anywhere except in this file.

Comment: You can't call a function that doesn't exists. It must exists

Comment: Yeah, but @wizkid code is works. I can show all except age_range.

Comment: But it is impossible to tell you why if we don't know what checkUser does

Comment: @wizkid Any reference that explain more clear about topic login with facebook with PHP?

Comment: I try to delete checkUser and change to getUser (not works). It work when use CheckUser. But anywhere I didn't see checkUser. I'm confused

Comment: @LatifRahmat How about the FB docs instead of just copying something you don't understand? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login

Comment: @Tobi Any reference for full source code? in your link it's just sample. I'm confused about it too. Maybe from configuration. Thanks before

Comment: `age_range` is not a scalar value, but an object – and as such, you can not embed it into a string this way. You need to access the individual properties of the object.

Comment: @Wizkid : Hi I have update code function of checkUser. What's solve about it?

Comment: @LatifRahmat Well, you should be able to transfer the official example into working code. StackOverflow is NOT a programming service.

Comment: @Tobi, How I can show age_range? thanks